# "Cannot use absolute pathname" Error

Tags: python

im trying to install a python library for some software I just downloaded, and I'm getting this error when I run the library install from the command line. The error occures when it hits this point

`INFO 2015-02-14 13:47:20, 467 Main Thread _7ZipController.unzip.13 running:C:\users\desktop\BBOS\tools\7-Zip\7za.exe x -y -oC:\user\desktop\BBOS\New Folderr\Lib\Site-package C:\user\Desktop\BBOS\New Folder\Lib\Site-Packages\pymysql.7z`

I'm not real familiar with python, so forgive me if this isn't enough information. If you need more info, i can try and provide as much as possible!

EDIT:

the software im trying to install is called "baseball on a stick" its a software package that extracts files from MLB.com and then places them into a MySQL database. This error occurs when I try and install the "installPythonLibs.py" file that comes with the software. If you need to know more about the software, you can google "Baseball on a stick" and it should be one of the first links to SourceForge. There is a video on there as well that shows exactly what i'm trying to do, but for some reason it doesn't work when I try and do it. Hopefully this is enough extra information. here is the link to the software and video https://sourceforge.net/projects/baseballonastic/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us the actual error and the full traceback if possible?  And how you're trying to install it?

Comment: “a library” for “some software”… I’m afraid, you have to be more specific than that.

Comment: Updated post for more information

Comment: Can you just include the specific link so we can avoid confusion?

Comment: Yes sorry, the only reason I didn't was because I jave been told in the past not to post links or my post would be shut down

Comment: The post now includes the link to what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Could you please show us the specific commands you type into the command line prompt, and the specific (and complete) error traceback you get?  And the only reason you would be asked to not include links would be if they're spammy or harmful in some way.

Comment: The command is `C:\Users\Desktop\BBOS\src>installPythonLibs.py` and the error message in the original post is the only error I get.

Comment: I've taken out the space in `New Folder` as suggested by @burhan_Khalid. This now results in a window opening up and asking me which application I would like to use to open the file when I run `C:\Users\Desktop\BBOS\src>installPythonLibs.py`.

Comment: Try entering `python installPythonLibs.py` to the command line

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that you have a path component with a space in its name.

```
C:\user\Desktop\BBOS\New Folder\Lib\Site-Packages\pymysql.7z
                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The bigger problem is that this is not how you install Python packages; you just need to run:

```
pip install pymysql
```

From a command prompt (ie, from `cmd.exe`).

Comment: Hmmm, I changed the folder name to not have a space, but now when I run that `installPythonLibs.py` it opens up a window asking me which file I want to open. What i'm trying to do might be more clear if you google "baseball on a stick" and click on the source forge link. There they have a video of exactly what I'm trying to do. It works perfectly for them, but not me.